# Why my CSS file called by its URL returns the current page or the homepage

Tags: html, css, url, redirect, server

here is my problem. I'm working on a pre-production Laravel website that is not reading the CSS file. ( Fortunately, the production site is functioning correctly.).

When I call mysite.com page the css is loaded (it's return a code 200). But it is not being applied.

And when I want to test the url monsite.com/css/app.css it's return the current page (in my case it's the home page).

To debug, I modified my index.php file with a few lines of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I added an "exit" statement top stop all scripts.

In the css/app.css file, if I tried:

```
h1 { color: red }
```

When I visit my homepage, I see "Hello" in red. If I look at mysite.com/css/app.css, I can see my CSS.

So it's work fine.

I can add CSS gradually, and it works until a point where:

"Hello" is no longer in red
mysite.com/css/app.css returns the homepage

I added some basic CSS for testing (I can potentially provide the CSS, but it's not really necessarily useful since it works on other sites, locally and on the production server).

Of course, once I encounter the bug, I try removing the latest CSS lines and it works. But those lines are not the ones causing the issue:

I can remove any line, and it works
If I replace the last added CSS lines with others, it still bugs
I assumed it could be the file size; it bugs around 1.1 KB, which is small. I'm wondering if I have a file closure issue...

Maybe it's a configuration server problem.I don't know.

Remember:

- the url is ok, it is always return code 200, it means that the route is correct, name, etc (I think)
- when there is few css it is working

If you have any suggestions, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have tried several CSS files that work elsewhere.
I have tried line by line: adding/removing/modifying.
I code a really light html page to test.

In all cases, at some point, I encounter the bug without identifying a specific line.

Normally I shoud be able to do mysite/css/app.css to show the css. It is only do with a few lines.